# Move an SVN respository when the server is dead

Tags: svn, repository, move

My SVN server is dead.

I have another machine I could use as an SVN server and a couple of machines with working copies of the original repository.

Is there a clean way to recreate the repository on a new server, from only a current working copy? (history can be forgotten)

I have attempted creating a new repository, hacking its UUID and checking in the complete directory structure, then switch -relocate'ing the working copies, but this doesn't work due to checksums and revision numbers not matching.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Is the disk destroyed, or can you install it in another machine and copy the repository directory?

Comment: If you don't care about history why care about preserving your working copy? Just import what you have to a totally new repo and then check out a new working copy. ???

Comment: Anon- The disk's still there, but I don't have another desktop machine handy. I might have to dig out an IDE/USB adapter... Nathan- I suppose I could do this; I was hoping I might be able to revive the history-holding machine at some point though, so I could get what history is there back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no backups whatsoever?

If that's the case, then the simplest approach will be to create a new repository, import the contents of one working directory into it, and then have everyone else check out clean from the new repository. Trying to hack the existing working directories will be more trouble than it's worth.

You'll want to make sure that the "master" working directory is clean: do an `svn revert` on it, then remove all `.svn` directories -- note that there's one at every level of the tree (definitely make a copy before doing this this).

If you want to preserve changes in other working directories, then you can remove the `.svn` directories from them and use a tool like `cpio` to copy the files into the new working directories.

Comment: Thanks for the full response! I have a backup from several months ago, but when I use that to create a new repository it complains about mismatching checksums... I guess starting afresh is the only way! I might rename all my .svns as .svn-backup just so I can go back to my old repository should I ever revive the machine. Thanks again!

Comment: @Rick - the `svnadmin setuuid` command might help you get past the checksum issue. However, I think you'd be better off creating the repo from backup, checking out into a new working directory, then copying the latest files using the process above.

Comment: Ok, I did this (with the renamed rather than deleted .svns) - unfortunately, I completely forgot there are files and directories I don't check in (build directories etc), so I'm now going to have a bit of a headache stripping them. Bah... Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to abandon the history, you could create a new repository and add your working copy as its new content. In order to do this, however, you need to remove all `.svn` folders first. Some scripting could do that.

Be sure to do all this with a copy of your working copy, as it seems to be the last thing you have to cling to.

Comment: Is there any way to preserve history and yet import repository into newly created repo.

Answer (score 2):

`svn export` is the right way to remove .svn folders.

Comment: But does this even work when you don't have access to the SVN server? (And how does this answer the question?)

Comment: -1: His server with the repo on it is dead!  svn export won't help here unless the hard drive is recoverable.

Comment: @jgifford25: Note that you can export into a working copy, which is a way to remove all `.svn` folders. However, as I've written, I doubt this works without the repo being accessible. ICBWT.

Comment: It definitely lets you export from a working copy (just run svn help export, see option #2), without the server. From the working copy dir, "svn export . /path/to/export/to". This will save the OP from needing to write a script to delete the .svn dirs himself, plus it will omit any files not under version control, all without modifying his working copy.